# NSDictionary error on real device

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary

Following code work fine on emulator, but on real device i got exception:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"] == nil)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *favorites = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favorites forKey:@"favorites"];
}
```

Exception on next line of code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *favorites = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"]];
```

Here debugger message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'*** -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:]: dictionary argument is not
an NSDictionary'
```

I use iPad device with iOS 7.1.

**EDIT**

On real devise the old version of the application used this key in NSUserDefaults for NSArray. Thanks for help!

Comment: True. The object is not an NSDictionary. It is instead, a NSMutableDictionary. You need to store a NSDictionary in userDefaults in the first place.

Comment: I have tried to do so, but it does not work. @akashg

Comment: Please provide us additional information, which objects you store in this NSDictionairy, I think the serialization/deserialization of these objects is not implemented correctly and leaks might occur, which would also explain the "copyItems:" aspect

Comment: There's no difference between an NSDictionary and an NSMutableDictionary. It's no problem storing a mutable dictionary.

Comment: I think at very first time the NSUseDefaults returning nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what is already stored in your user preferences is not a dictionary.

You could change the test at the beginning like this:

```
if (! [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favourites"] 
           isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
```

This will cover the case that there is nothing in your user defaults, or that you have an object there that isn't a dictionary.